VB.NET Using System.Security.AccessControl
I developed an application to block access to opening, renaming, deleting, or copying a folder. I used VB.NET Framework 4.0. The codes for locking and unlocking are as follows:
'Folder lock code:
Dim Path = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("D:\FolderName")
Path.MoveTo("D:\FolderName" & ".{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}")
Path.Attributes = System.IO.FileAttributes.System
Dim FSS As System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity = _
           System.IO.File.GetAccessControl("D:\FolderName" & _
           ".{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}")
FSS.AddAccessRule(New System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule _
           (Environment.UserName, System.Security.AccessControl. _
           FileSystemRights.FullControl, System.Security. _
           AccessControl.AccessControlType.Deny))
System.IO.File.SetAccessControl("D:\FolderName" & _
           ".{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}", FSS)

'Folder unlock code:
Dim FSS As System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity = _
           System.IO.File.GetAccessControl("D:\FolderName")
FSS.RemoveAccessRule(New System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule _
           (Environment.UserName, System.Security.AccessControl. _
           FileSystemRights.FullControl, System.Security. _
           AccessControl.AccessControlType.Deny))
System.IO.File.SetAccessControl("D:\FolderName", FSS)
Dim Path = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("D:\FolderName")
Path.MoveTo(Replace("D:\FolderName", ".{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}", ""))
Path.Attributes = System.IO.FileAttributes.Normal

I tested the app on several folders and it worked perfectly. There is only one folder, named MP3, that I could not unlock. It is a folder with audio files with .mp3 extension. I get the error "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation".
I can't find anything about this folder that is different from all the others that lock and unlock perfectly. I also used run as administrator.
I can't even access it manually to unlock it because the Security tab is missing from the all locked folders properties. In this situation, I'm asking if anyone knows a method to unlock this folder? Thanks a lot for any suggestions!
